# Spring Security with JWT token is loading spring UserDetails object on every request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am learning spring security with JWT token and spring boot. I have implemented it properly and it is working fine. But I have one doubt in how JwtRequestFilter works. I have gone through couple of websites to understand spring security with spring boot and found same thing. So let me go to main doubt. 
I am adding JwtRequestFilter file below.

**JwtRequestFilter.java**

```
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Autowired
private JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;
@Autowired
private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    String username = null;
    String jwtToken = null;

    // JWT Token is in the form "Bearer token". Remove Bearer word and get
    // only the Token
    if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
        try {
            username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
        }
    } else {
        logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
    }
    // Once we get the token validate it.
    if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
         // This below line is calling on every request
        UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        // if token is valid configure Spring Security to manually set
        // authentication
        if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
            .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            // After setting the Authentication in the context, we specify
            // that the current user is authenticated. So it passes the
            // Spring Security Configurations successfully.
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

}

As highlighed to validate token we have to provide spring UserDetails object and we are getting spring UserDetails object from jwtUserDetailsService. So every request this filter will call then token verification will perform and we have to call jwtUserDetailsService on every request. 
My doubt is inside my jwtUserDetailsService I am adding couple of validation and adding user privileges. So on every request below steps are repeated in jwtUserDetailsService.

1. Get user using username from DB.
2. Get user role
3. Get user privileges from DB.
4. Assign privileges to userDetails.

JwtUserDetailsService.java

```
@Service("jwtUserDetailsService")
@Transactional
public class JwtUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private IUserService service;

@Autowired
private MessageSource messages;

@Autowired
private RoleRepository roleRepository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)
  throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    if (user == null) {
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
          " ", " ", true, true, true, true, 
          getAuthorities(Arrays.asList(
            roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_USER"))));
    }

    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
      user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(), true, true, 
      true, getAuthorities(user.getRoles()));
}

private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(
  Collection<Role> roles) {

    return getGrantedAuthorities(getPrivileges(roles));
}

private List<String> getPrivileges(Collection<Role> roles) {

    List<String> privileges = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Privilege> collection = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Role role : roles) {
        collection.addAll(role.getPrivileges());
    }
    for (Privilege item : collection) {
        privileges.add(item.getName());
    }
    return privileges;
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> privileges) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String privilege : privileges) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(privilege));
    }
    return authorities;
}
}
```

So on every request these queries are executing. Is there any better way of doing this? Because once I am adding user privileges in spring UserDetails object why we need to do that again on every request. Or those have scope of request only. I have worked on spring mvc and once we add privileges in spring UserDetails object it will be there until I am hitting logout means It will be there in spring security context until we remove it. Will it be same in spring boot? If I am adding role and privileges details once in spring UserDetails object why we need to add it again?

Comment: Why are you implementing your own filter when there is already a jwt filter in spring security 5

Comment: @ThomasAndolf, Sorry I have just started learning this. So I was not aware that spring security 5 provide such functionality. Can you please provide any link so I can go throght it to understand concept. Thanks.

Comment: too many people google and read old tutorials. Always go their own documentation first. It's actually really good https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#webflux-oauth2-resource-server-sans-boot

Comment: @ThomasAndolf, Thanks I will look into it.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf At least they are googling :-). I am looking at the docs and I don't see a JWT filter in the list (I've seen people extending the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter or OncePerFilter). I see a token filter under OAuth, but he's not implementing OAuth above. https://dev.to/d_tomov/jwt-bearer-authentication-authorization-with-spring-security-5-in-a-spring-boot-app-2cfe

Comment: It is named `BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter` All you need to do is search for ”jwt” in the documentation.

Comment: You can also refer to this:

JWT authentication without fetching user details on each request


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50572339/jwt-authentication-without-fetching-user-details-on-each-request

Answer (score 0):

> So every request this filter will call then token verification will
>   perform and we have to call jwtUserDetailsService on every request.

This can't be correct since you have a condition `if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null)`.

So the first time the token was validated, you query your user details service, fetch all grants and set them to the Security context (you are already doing it: `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);`).

Furthermore, with the JWT auth you usually don't even need to access any user details service since all grants ideally should be contained in the token itself. So the only thing you need to do is validating token's signature.

Comment: I agree with you that on every request it should not call jwtUserDetailsService. Here, my front end is angular so every time I am getting request SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() is always null. From angular, I am passing token in a header. Do I need to pass any other parameter? As per my knowledge, the filter will be called before spring security and hence we cannot get a user from SecurityContextHolder. Because how we are going identify which user authentication object from spring security context holder. Please let me if I am wrong.

Comment: You might have registered your filter wrongly. Can you add `SecurityConfig` code (where you actually add this filter to the filter chain)?

Answer (score 0):

Once an user logs in his authentication is established, so you don't need to do db call again, after login in every request user should be checked for authorization only with the roles being set in the token during authentication, you need to validate the token is not tampered in every request 
instead of creating userdetails by loading user detail from db call

UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

you could also encode the user's username and roles inside JWT claims
 and create the UserDetails object by parsing those claims from the JWT.